# Run Solr Control Script in Kubernetes

Tags: solr, kubernetes, solrcloud

I have a [Kubernetes](https://kubernetes.io/) installation with Zookeeper and [Solr 6.0](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/) services correctly installed. We can call *solr-node-x* any Solr instance.
In order to check Solr Health I would like to use the [Solr Control Script for HealthChek](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Solr+Control+Script+Reference#SolrControlScriptReference-Healthcheck) that normally would be called locally using for instance:

```
$ bin/solr healthcheck -c gettingstarted -z localhost:9865
```

How can I run that command against Solr within a Kubernetes deployment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid having a local instance of `bin/solr`, you can use the one inside one of your containers.

Depending on the image you're using, you can call any script in your container by using `kubectl exec`.

Usually it's a good idea to start by exploring the layout [inside your container by getting a shell](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/debug-application-cluster/get-shell-running-container/):

```
kubectl exec -it <name of container> -- /bin/bash
```

When you have the location of the `bin/solr` script inside your container you can call it directly:

```
kubectl exec -it <name of container> -- /path/to/bin/solr healthcheck -c gettingstarted -z localhost:9865
```

Comment: Quick and concise, it works like a charm. Thank you.